# Why does /n not function on a TextBox with Multiline and AcceptsReturn set to True

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've been attempting to work with the \n in a TextBox with Multiline, and AcceptsReturn set to true. I have looked around and tried \r\n (without any better result) and also creating a String to host "Environment.NewLine" called CRLF, but this approach seems excessive. I've checked MSDN, and multiple entries here on Stackoverflow, but I'm coming up blank. What I find funny is that the text output still contains the new line when I paste said output to any other source. My output window using Console.Write() as well as my CRLF entries work without a hitch.

Here is a copy of the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private String CRLF = Environment.NewLine;
        private String test = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void btnNewManifest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test = "Hello World 1\nHello World 2" + CRLF + "Hola!";
            txtOutput.Text = test;
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Grant.  Neither \n nor \r\n work for me. I was hoping to be able to use something that was easier to read / faster to type hence the String CRLF = "Environment.NewLine"; this however leaves me at square one.

Comment: I was premature there. "Environment.NewLine" was always working. I found using it inline or accessing it via a String "CRLF" to be too verbose. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have no clue either. It's working now just fine. Best guess is "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\r\n` for Windows, but I'd still recommend using [`Environment.NewLine`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline) as this will make your code run properly on all platforms.

The following code works fine on Windows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public TextBox txtOutput = new TextBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.txtOutput.Width = 200;
        this.txtOutput.Height = 100;
        this.txtOutput.Multiline = true;
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtOutput);

        this.txtOutput.Text = "My test\r\nNext line";
    }
}
```

Use this code and compare it to the textbox you have to try and figure out what else is up. I think there's something else going on behind the scenes.

By the way, you could do something like this (works for me), but I'm not sure it would work on other systems:

```
this.txtOutput.Text = 
@"Line one
Line two
Line three";
```

Comment: Thanks, David. Your suggestion and solution are sound. I had been trying to use the \r\n the last couple of nights and somehow it was not working so I resorted to the Environment.NewLine. Odd that I try the \r\n today and it works.